# Using "such" and "as", together and segregated

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

Here are two variations:

1. I would like you to buy such fruit as apples and watermelon for me.
2. Can you buy me some fruit such as apples or watermelon?

Is there any blatant difference or a fine one that we should know related to their usage? can both forms be used in place of each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *I would like you to buy such fruit as apples and watermelon for me.*

You want someone to buy you fruit. The fruit has to be either apples and/or watermelons.

- *Can you buy me some fruit such as apples or watermelon?*

You want someone to buy you fruit. Some examples of fruits are apples and watermelons.

The first one, the sentence focuses on the specific item (specific fruit). The second one focuses on the fact that you want fruit but it doesn't matter which one just as long as it is fruit and you cite some references for the individual you've asked to purchase it for you.

I would say that there is a fine difference as both imply that you want apples and watermelon, except one is very specific while the other leaves it open to interpretation (e.g. you can get them a pear as it is like an apple).

Comment: I disagree that “such fruit[s] as apples and watermelon[s]” limits the options to those two types of fruit. In an example phrase quite typical of things often seen here on ELU itself, “This [word/construction/form] has been used by such respected penmen as Shakespeare, Milton, and Byron for hundreds of years”, it is quite clear that the three writers mentioned are only _examples_, not an exhaustive list.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Based on [Strunk and the Elements of Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Strunk,_Jr.), the position of words like 'such', 'which', 'where', etc, creates a conditional statement if they are succeeded by the subject. If it is located before it then the sentence becomes restrictive (e.g. 'that'). If I might add, based on its usage the 'restriction' would normally be ignored as most people would emphasis the restriction if it were important (e.g. I would like you to buy me such fruit as apples and watermelons *only*).

Comment: Don’t forget that _The Elements of Style_ is often not only highly idiosyncratic, but also erratic and outdated. I’m not quite following your description in the first few lines, so I can’t really comment on that—but in actual usage, I doubt many people would perceive any difference, other than in formality and register, between “such things as Y” and “things such as Y”.

Comment: *The Elements of Style* is still very much used today especially for technical and scientific papers as a guide to style and construction. Of course it has been updated to keep up with the times (1918 is a long time ago, there are newer versions). My third paragraph in the answer did state that there is a fine/subtle difference between the two sentences and, as you pointed out, not many people would perceive it.

Comment: IMO "such fruit as" doesn't necessarily restrict it to only apples/watermelons, but it does imply a stronger restriction than "fruit such as". Perhaps using fruit isn't the best example though, since the distinction is harder to see. Another example might be "foolish things such as X" vs. "such foolish things as X". The former has a nuance of referring to all foolish things of which X is just an example, compared to the latter which scopes the referent to only tomfoolery similar to X. It's only an weak implicature though, context could easily override it to force it one way or the other.